# How to Sniff Upper Level of the Local Network?

Tags: networking, sniffing

So, I am basically a newbie pen tester and I am studying sniffing.

I have 4 machines and 2 routers and decided to test some sniffing techniques. So I created a setup like this.

Setup Image
[image: Setup Image]

Router1 → PC1, PC2, Router2, PC4

Router2 → PC3

So I want to Sniff all the Traffic between PC1, PC2, PC4 from my PC3.
Is that practically possible?

I have Admin access to Both routers and all the PCs.

Comment: Why two routers?   Are the routers on the same subnet?  Different subnets?  Are you using any routing protocols between the two routers?  What brand/model of router are you using?  What application are you planning on using to capture the traffic?   What OS are you running on each computer?

Comment: Sorry but another routers were just laying around.. no particular reason. Just wanted to try something. all pcs have windows and PC3 also has kali installed(yes I am a newbie, forgive me). I thought of using ettercap in linux or cain & abel in windows. TP link and tenda routers.

Comment: I do not mean to sound like I am talking down to you or anything, so please dont take it that way - but you really need to learn the fundamentals of networking before you will be able to wrap your head around dissecting a packet capture.   I would suggest if you are interested in the topic, go take a look at a book that covers the Network+ certification.  It is relatively easy for anyone with a technical background. That will hopefully teach you some of the foundational networking concepts that are going to be essential if you are interested in the subject matter.

Comment: no no I didn't take it any other way. as a matter of fact I have strong foundation in networking as a computer science engineer. And unfortunately theoretically I know how to sniff from the above architecture. but I don't have enough practical experience to pull it off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to need a managed switch that has a feature commonly referred to as port mirroring (also commonly called port monitoring or SPAN) in order to see unicast (transmissions between computers other than your own) traffic between computers.  Without port mirroring, all you will see will be broadcasts (like DHCP requests) and multicast traffic (commonly used for inter router communication).

Another option would be to get a network hub to interconnect all of your PCs to.  hubs are layer 1 devices, so no intelligent choices are being made at layer 2 (which is where MAC addresses come into play).  Packets that go through switches (which are layer 2 devices) will only get forwarded to the port with a specific destination MAC address defined in the packet, which is why on most networks switches are preferred over hubs.

Comment: Thanks. too much work. I am gonna skip the testing and just study the theories only.

Comment: too much work?   if you are interested in the subject there should be no such thing as "too much work".

Comment: I was hoping there was a software solution to this problem. I researched port mirroring as you mentioned. But I want the router1 to be constant. I mean I don't want to mess with router1 but Anything after that I can change. But port mirroring at second level will also not suffice would it?